# I can't rotate the screen back and all clicking is messed up

Tags: debian, xfce

Yesterday at 3 AM I was messing around with settings and this happened.
[image: oh]

Whenever I right-click, the right-click menu appears somewhere else, and I already tried everything such as running `startxfce && xrandr -o normal`, expecting it to rotate when I logged in, but still it remains like this.

Comment: Does `xrandr -o normal`, once you are in the session, work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to Applications->Settings->Display and change the rotation there.

Or edit `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` and set the `Rotation` value to `0`.